# Selecionar múltiplos checkbox com foreach, vindo do banco em laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, checkbox

Estou populando um checkbox com as informações do banco, estou tentando fazer com que ele leia todos os checkbox selecionados.

Controller

```
    public function store(RequestProduto $request)
{
    $data = new Produtos;
    $data->nome_visivel = $request->nome_visivel;
    $data->nome = $request->nome;
    $data->pdf = $request->pdf;
    $data->keywords = $request->keywords;
    $data->save();

    return Redirect::to('adm/produto')->with('return', 'Dados salvos com sucesso');
}
```

View

```
@foreach($atributos as $key => $value)
        <input type="checkbox" name="nome[]" value="{{$value->nome}}">{{$value->nome}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Como você sabe que ele está selecionado ? Não entendi muito bem o que você precisa.

Comment: @Gumball eu não quero só que ele salve apenas um valor do checkbox, preciso que ele me retorne todos os valores selecionados

Comment: É que você não postou o `HTML` completo, entendi a pergunta, cada nome pertence a um novo produto ou todos esses nomes vão ser salvos no mesmo produto? nome = checkbox's selecionados, certo?

Comment: Isso @KennyRafael

Comment: Se eu deixar o name="nome", ele salva apenas o ultimo check

Comment: Mas você vai concatenar todos eles para salvar ou cada um vai gerar um registro novo?

Comment: Quero concatenar todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O parâmetro é recebido como array, basta dar um `implode()` nos dados para     concatenar:

```
public function store(RequestProduto $request)
{
    $data = new Produtos;
    $data->nome_visivel = $request->nome_visivel;
    $data->nome = implode(' - ', $request->nome); // onde o primeiro parâmetro é o separador dos itens
    $data->pdf = $request->pdf;
    $data->keywords = $request->keywords;
    $data->save();

    return Redirect::to('adm/produto')->with('return', 'Dados salvos com sucesso');
}
```

Comment: Deu isso aqui: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: Agora foi... muito obrigado, eu tinha esquecido de receber o nome como array... vc me salvou! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Haha, que bom que acertou, considere marcar a resposta como correta caso tenha ajudado, você também pode dar um vote up na mesma pela contribuição!